# How do I show user message "New Record added" after Successful insert into DB - Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, validation, forms

I want to show a message after Successful insert next to input field , im using zend validation on the form to display validation errors, but want to confirm to user that the data has been added to the db , getting a bit stuck ?

last section of code block:

```
 if (!$errors) {
      // insert the details in the database
      $data = array('OptionGroupName'  => $_POST['OptionGroupName']);

       $insert = $dbwa_ecommerce->insert('optiongroups', $data);

       header('Location: testzendval.php');

       // want to show message on form after insert ?

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the FlashMessenger action helper. You basically use the helper to put a message in the session and retrieve it after redirection.

Manual : http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

Here's a blog post explaining how to do it : http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-frameworks-flash-messenger-action-helper/

Comment: where do you put this ?$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Task saved');
$this->_helper->redirector('index');

Comment: $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
 struggling with this whole concept ?, also every time i press return it posts the message half finished !

Comment: You only need `$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Task saved');`. Put that in your controller before you redirect. And ` $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages()` goes into your master controller when you're pulling out the messages and assigning to the view.